# Blender/GPU issue, system not running AMD proprietary drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, amdgpu, gpu-driver, blender

Edits to clarify:

Will the amdgpu-pro driver work with an RX 460? I got it from the amd downloads for rx 460...

I was hoping to CPU + GPU render in Blender, but as of now it still says,
"no compatible GPUs found for path tracing" in preferences. I was hoping an updated pro driver would fix this. Eevee runs fine, and even cycles but I was hoping to use both to render.

Either way, It seems like the open source driver is running still anyway.

System info:
I'm using Blender 2.92.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.  I have a budget system with an RX 460, and I just installed the most current amd proprietary drivers (20.50 release) (pro stack)

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

outputs:

```
description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             ...
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
```

i had already installed the amdgpu-pro driver with:

```
$ ./amdgpu-pro-install -y --opencl=pal,legacy
```

except that it then asked me to instead run

```
./amdgpu-pro-install -y --opencl=rocr
```

Which I did, and it says it was installed if i run it again.

So is it still using the open source driver? Should I have uninstalled that first? I mean of course I ran across plenty of other comments in similar scenarios ( with other gpus), but of course I don't want to start --purge this and --uninstall that several times over recklessly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a little post-install in order to Blender see your GPU. Add your user to video and render groups.

sudo usermod -a -G video $USERNAME
sudo usermod -a -G render $USERNAME

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. To be honest, I dont know what you mean exactly. When I put that in the terminal, it just gave me a list of usage options for usermod, starting with: "Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN" , then all the command options for usermod.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it looks like the pro drivers were installed after all.

running:

```
dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
```

gets me this.

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version       Architecture Description
+++-==============-=============-============-==============================================
ii  amdgpu-pro     20.50-1234664 amd64        Meta package to install amdgpu Pro components.
```

I remember that was the number I installed. So then question is, why isn't Blender recognizing any openCL support?